# Changing default resolution system-wide in Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: unity, lightdm, login-screen, display-resolution, 15.10

Ubuntu 15.10 uses the native resolution of the screen by default. The native resolution on my laptop (3200*1800) is too big for the size of the screen (13"), leading to a very high pixel density, it makes it hard to use the UI.

I have changed the display settings after logging in, but when the computer boots up the resolution remains too high and it only changes after logging in. Terminal sessions (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and so on) also have this resolution after boot which makes the text unreadable.

I'd like to change (or limit?) the default resolution to 1920*1080 so that the login screen and terminal sessions are using that resolution right after the computer has booted up.

Only the default window manager is installed (lightdm + unity).

Comment: There are many answers online that relate to much older versions of Ubuntu. None of them are useful.